# I cannot see my windows 10 PC from my MacBookPro even with the sharing settings on

Tags: windows-10, macos, file-sharing, macos-mojave

I have enabled file and printer sharing on my Windows 10 Pro PC.

[image]

However the PC does not appear on the Network in Finder

[image]

Both of them connect to the same wifi network, and I am able to connect to the PC using Remote Desktop. So why I cannot see it in Network?

Comment: What version of SMB are you using?

Comment: Mojave is using SMB3 (https://help.apple.com/deployment/macos/#/ior96b240d12)